# convert select request result to an array in nodejs using mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

i am executing this select request in mysql data base and nodejs, the expected results are only an array with string content containing the link : ['http://hgj','http://jfhd'], but with the code that i will insert it shows me : [{link:''http://hgj},{link:''http://jfhd}] how can i remove the objects {link} and insert in the table only the string 'http...'?

```js
 query = "select link from weblist";
        var res=  await con.query(query, (error, response) => {
        console.log('link from database', error || response);
        var table = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
       return table ;
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few simple steps involved in this solution:

1. Stringify the object using `JSON.stringify`. This is now a string
2. The string contains chars you don't want so you use `string.replace()` and pass a regex literal that irrespective of char position or casing, it removes the unwanted char with "" (i.e.nothing);
3. return that new string with a representation of your urls inside an array

One-liner solution:

```
let oneliner = links.map((elem) => {
    return JSON.stringify(elem).replace(/[{}"'link:]/gi, "");
})

console.log(oneliner);

// [ 'http: //hgj', 'http://jfhd' ]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but how can i remove  the "link" too, so to be clear in my array i want to have only ['http://hgj' , 'http://jfhd']